# How to add Excel Dynamic Filter formula by VBA

Tags: vba, microsoft-office, macros

I need Filter formula for ms office 2016. But it's not available. How can I add it by VBA. If anyone know kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1):

FILTER function is available only in recent versions of Excel 365.

It's core part of Excel, not an additional package, there is no way to add it through VBA.

of course you can create a custom function in VBA working similarly, however implementing it is just too big task to be able to answer here.